# Labels are updating late after logging in with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I try to solve this simple problem but I definitely don't understand what I am doing wrong.

I have two view controllers, `LoginVC` and `HomeVC`.
After authentication on the `LoginVC` the user gets to the `HomeVC` where I have a function that checks if the user is logged in and fetch data from Firebase.

When `HomeVC` appears, the `UIImageView` gets a photo from FirebaseStorage immediately but all labels get data after 1 second.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    checkIfUserLogedIn()
}

//check if loged in and fill information
func checkIfUserLogedIn() {
    if FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid != nil {
        let uid = FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        FirebaseDatabase.Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (DataSnapshot) in
             if let dictionary =  DataSnapshot.value as? [String: String] {
                 //update labels
                 self.nameLabel.text = dictionary["name"]
                 self.lastNameLabel.text = dictionary["lastName"]
                 self.ageLabel.text = dictionary["age"]
                 self.cityCountryLabel.text = dictionary ["cityCountry"]
                 self.phoneNumberLabel.text = dictionary ["phoneNumber"]
            }
        })

        //fetch photo to the UIImageView
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "usersPhoto/\(uid!).jpg")
        let placeHolder = UIImage(named: "placeholder.jpg")

        imageViewPhoto.sd_setImage(with: storageRef, placeholderImage: placeHolder)
        imageViewPhoto.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageViewPhoto.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        imageViewPhoto.layer.shadowColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8374180198, green: 0.8374378085, blue: 0.8374271393, alpha: 1)
        imageViewPhoto.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        imageViewPhoto.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        imageViewPhoto.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
        imageViewPhoto.layer.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        imageViewPhoto.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.921431005, green: 0.9214526415, blue: 0.9214410186, alpha: 1)
        imageViewPhoto.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    } else {
        return
    }
}
```

I tried:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    //upadte labels
    self.nameLabel.text = dictionary["name"]
    self.lastNameLabel.text = dictionary["lastName"]
    self.ageLabel.text = dictionary["age"]
    self.cityCountryLabel.text = dictionary ["cityCountry"]
    self.phoneNumberLabel.text = dictionary ["phoneNumber"]
}
```

Also I tried:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
    //upadte labels
    self.nameLabel.text = dictionary["name"]
    self.lastNameLabel.text = dictionary["lastName"]
    self.ageLabel.text = dictionary["age"]
    self.cityCountryLabel.text = dictionary ["cityCountry"]
    self.phoneNumberLabel.text = dictionary ["phoneNumber"]
}
})
```

Comment: @matt the OP says they tried to wrap that UIKit code in a call to `DispatchQueue.main.async()` but that didn't help.

Comment: You should initialize your view with the data:   HomeVC(userData) That way the view can populate the labels instantly. While your waiting on the callback consider using a loading indicator on the login screen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the  FireBase `observeSingleEvent(of:with:)` function is async, and calls it's completion handler on a background thread. You should look in the FireBase docs to confirm that.

If that is the case then you **would** need to wrap your UI code in a call to `DispatchQeueue.main.async(execute:)`. (All UIKit calls need to be done from the main thread.

There is no difference between the two versions of your call to `DispatchQeueue.main.async`. One version uses "trailing closure" syntax where you skip the function parens and the label on the `execute` parameter, and the other form uses normal "longhand" function calling syntax. The effect of both versions is identical.